# eledmac/eledpar/LuaTeX: right alignment of RTL text paragraphs in pages enviroment

Tags: luatex, eledmac, eledpar, syriac

I have a LuaTex + `eledmac` + `eledpar` setup for critical editions in syriac and english (on facing pages). Strangely, the syriac text, which is running RTL, is not aligned on the right, but on the left side of the column as soon as I am in the `\begin{pages}...\end{pages}` structure of `eledpar`.

The following MWE demonstrates what I mean. Can anyone help me make the syriac text of the `\eledsection` and of the following syriac paragraph align to the right side of the whole page?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newfontfamily\syriacfont[Script=Syriac,Scale=1.2]{estre.otf}

\newcommand{\textsyriac}[1] % Syriac inside LTR
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\syriacfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\n}         [1] % for digits inside Arabic text
           {\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\syriacfootnote} [1] % Syriac Footnotes
           {\footnote{\textsyriac{#1}}}
\newenvironment{syriac}     % Syriac paragraph
           {\luatextextdir TRT\luatexpardir TRT\syriacfont}{}

\begin{document}
The following syriac paragraph appears right-aligned as a whole: 

\begin{syriac}
        1ܘܟܕ 2ܡܿܟܪܟܝ3ܢܢ ܐܪܟ4ܐܢܐ ܗ̄ 5ܡܘܪܐ6 ܗܿܝ ܩ7ܕܡܝܬܐ
\end{syriac}

\bigskip

But on the next page, neither the syriac section heading nor the syriac
paragraph are right-aligned, although they are correctly typsetted RTL: 

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\begin{syriac}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
%% This text is aligned on the left, but should be on the right: 
       \eledsection*{\textsyriac{ܡܿܟܪܟܝ}}
   \pend

   \pstart
       \begin{syriac}
%% This text is aligned on the left, but should be on the right: 
        1ܘܟܕ 2ܡܿܟܪܟܝ3ܢܢ ܐܪܟ4ܐܢܐ ܗ̄ 5ܡܘܪܐ6 ܗܿܝ ܩ7ܕܡܝܬܐ
       \end{syriac}
   \pend
\endnumbering
\end{syriac}
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
       \eledsection{English headline} 
   \pend

   \pstart
        Some english text. 
   \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\Pages
\end{pages} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you absolutly need LuaLaTeX? because eledmac/eledpar has not implemented yet direction mechanism of LuaLaTeX, but only these of XeLaTeX. see the file parallel-column-two-languages.tex in the "examples" folder of the handbook.

Comment: as the only one maintener of eledmac, I can say something : i have no time for lualatex implementation.

Comment: Ah ok, I see it is because of LuaTeX. But do you think I can fix this by providing some replacement for the many `\if@RTL` that occur in the `eledmac.sty`/`eledpar.sty`, or will it be more complicated than this?

Comment: I think it will be more complex. Those \if@RTL are principaly for footnotes. When eledmac split the text in lines, it retains, with XeLaTeX + bidi the orientation. It seems it's not the case with LuaLaTeX. Open an issue on github, I could look for it ... but I can't say when.

Comment: yes, I confirm. It's more complex.

Comment: Ah all right. Thanks a lot; I will see what I can find out. I will post further results here if there are any.

Comment: I have a pist..

Comment: ok, I think I obtains something goods. Cool you make test?

Comment: Dowload https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/lua-rtl.zip, run the two .ins file, obtains the .sty file and put them along your test.

Comment: could you test it ? it would be better thand loosing time to debug eledmac /eledpar by your self.

Comment: hi, any new? I would like to have feedback before publishing.

Comment: sorry i'm getting your messages only now i was on a trip. I will give you my result in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Yes, it works!! Thanks Maïeul, this is amazing. So would you still recommend switching to XeLaTeX (it's very big project, a book series for bilingual critical edition, so further problems might come up), or do you think it might be possible sticking with Lua in the near future?

Comment: I don't know. I think there is many case which I don't know. I suggest you to open a issue on github...

Comment: I will publish it on CTAN tomorrow night, after english correction...

Comment: open an issue when you have bug, of course ;-)

Comment: Maïeul, before you commit the changes, it seems the bugfix makes all the sidenotes (e.g. generated with `\ledsidenote`) appear one line too high ...

Comment: hum, please open an issue on github with MWE.

Comment: I am stil looking for the MWE.

Comment: try this version https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/1.18.0-1.12.0.zip. I think it should be solved.

Comment: Yes it works now! Thanks a lot. If there are more issues, I will post again on github. :) (And sorry for the delays, I'm on vacation this week.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 1.18.0 / 1.12.0 of eledmac/eledpar, just uploaded now on CTAN, should solve this issue.

Thanks for reporting it and for test.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, with XeLaTeX I can obtain what you need with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,polyglossia}
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{syriac}

\usepackage{bidi}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newfontfamily\syriacfont[Script=Syriac,Scale=1.2]{Estrangelo Edessa}


\newcommand{\n}         [1] % for digits inside Arabic text
           {\bgroup\LTR  #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\syriacfootnote} [1] % Syriac Footnotes
           {\footnote{\textsyriac{#1}}}

\let\bfseries\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{syriac}
\section*{ܘܟܕ}
\end{syriac}
The following syriac paragraph appears right-aligned as a whole: 

\begin{syriac}
        1ܘܟܕ 2ܡܿܟܪܟܝ3ܢܢ ܐܪܟ4ܐܢܐ ܗ̄ 5ܡܘܪܐ6 ܗܿܝ ܩ7ܕܡܝܬܐ
\end{syriac}

\bigskip

But on the next page, neither the syriac section heading nor the syriac
paragraph are right-aligned, although they are correctly typsetted RTL: 

%\newpage

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\begin{RTL}
\begin{syriac}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
%% This text is aligned on the left, but should be on the right: 
       \eledsection*{\syriacfont{ܘܟܕ}}
   \pend

   \pstart

%% This text is aligned on the left, but should be on the right: 
        1ܘܟܕ 2ܡܿܟܪܟܝ3ܢܢ ܐܪܟ4ܐܢܐ ܗ̄ 5ܡܘܪܐ6 ܗܿܝ ܩ7ܕܡܝܬܐ

   \pend
\endnumbering
\end{syriac}
\end{RTL}
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
       \eledsection{English headline} 
   \pend

   \pstart
        Some english text. 
   \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\Pages
\end{pages} 

\end{document}
```